# BBM integration in Blackberry webworks app?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks, bb-messenger

I developing an app where i need to integrate BlackBerry Messenger (BBM) in it. I am developing my app in Blackberry Webworks using Phonegap Plugin.  By following the [BBM SDK in Blackberry Webworks guide](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_services/bbm_sdk_for_ww_1878476_11.html), successfully executed sample app in BlackBerry webworks(without using phonegap plugin). But when i am using it with phonegap plugin not executing properly(getting blank screen). What the doubt raised for me is **does BBM supports/works properly using Phonegap Plugin in Blackberry Webworks.** When i am using with phonegap plugin it is showing only loading symbol & nothing more on screen.

**Can we use BlackBerry Messenger(BBM) with PhonePlugin in BlackBerry WebWorks...**

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

The BBM SDK is supported in BlackBerry WebWorks platform.  How ever, I am not sure whether the third party applications such as Phonegap has the support to BBM SDK.  You need to confirm this with Phone Gap.